# creating employee attendance app on google apps

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Hello i'm planning to create an application on google app engine, the application will provide the details of the employees attendance and their salary.

I'm going to use java for that, but i want to know is that idea possible on google apps ?

And another thing what kind of database i am going to use with google app ?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for GAE yet?  It will should give you the information you need to answer these questions for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, of course this is possible with [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html) (and [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html), and [Go](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/overview.html), if need be).

As for the database, App Engine uses a custom [High Replication datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html) that automatically takes care of replicating your data across multiple datacenters.

If you haven't already done so, have a look through the [costs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html) associated with App Engine, factor in how much you plan to scale your app and then decide if it's worth it to you.

Comment: +1 w/one side note...might be possible for OP to use Google Cloud SQL https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/ if s/he is willing to sign up for preview.

Comment: @Dave To be fair I don't know how well Cloud SQL is optimized, but I would venture to say the OP would probably get better performance using the _native_ HRD :)  Good point though!

Comment: On Cloud SQL vs High Replication Datastore:  If you have data that will be accessed concurrently by many users, go with the High Replication Datastore.  If you don't, and would like a more relational model to work with, use CloudSQL.